# Angular CDK virtual scroll experimental failing unit tests

Tags: angular, angular-cdk

I've add the CDK experimental scroll module to my component. Everything works fine but it is failing the test. Is this something I can control or is it an issue with the package?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

figured it out, cdk experimental 13.1.1 seems to be broken as switching to 12.0.0 works fine